# Cannot send any emails with Mailjet API

Tags: php, email, mailjet

I've registered an account at Mailjet service, got my API keys and trying to send a few test emails from my development server using library https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php.

I always get 401 Unauthorized answer, and in my account at mailjet.com there is a message:

"Your sending activity is currently suspended. Please contact our Support Team for more information."

Cannot get any reasonable answer from their support, only standard bot messages.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Show your code. How long have you waited for support to respond?

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with code.

Answer (score 5):

The issue has been solved.

If anyone will face the same problem - in my case it was because initially my account was "disabled" right after creation so I couldn't send any emails.

After long discussion with support they have enabled email sending capability.
Probably this is sort of an anti-spam measure from their side.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. What kind of service that suspends your account right after registration and subscription I wonder (I paid for basic plan). I'm gonna ask for a refund.

Comment: Same problem here, how you contact them please ? support page redirect on FAQ page ...

Comment: Same issue here, seems absolutely backwards for an email sending service